# how to come out of the for loop in socket program?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, ip

```
int CreateSocket()
{
struct sockaddr_in server, client;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int len;
int iResult;

//int count = 0;

//u_long iMode = 1;


    printf("Initializing Winsock\n");


    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD (1, 1);
    iResult =  WSAStartup (wVersionRequested, &wsaData);      
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
   printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n"); 


    // create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0)    {
        printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
        //return 0;
    }

    printf("Socket Created\n");  

//      iResult = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &iMode);
//if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
//  printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n", iResult);


    // create socket address of the server
    memset( &server, 0, sizeof(server));


    // IPv4 - connection
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // accept connections from any ip adress
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    // set port
    server.sin_port = htons(52428);


    //Binding between the socket and ip address
    if(bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }


    //Listen to incoming connections
    if(listen(sock, 10) == -1){
        printf("Listen failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Server has been successfully set up - Waiting for incoming connections");

    for(;;)   // accepting the connection continuously
    {
        len = sizeof(client);
        fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

        if(fd < 0)
        {
            printf("Accept failed\n");
        }
        else
        {
        printf("\n Process incoming connection from (%s , %d)", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),ntohs(client.sin_port));
        break;
        }

    }

}
void main()
{
    int data;

double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;


CreateSocket();

 Xcp_Initialize();

    while(1)
        {
            data = recv(fd, recv_data, 99, 0);
            if (data == SOCKET_ERROR) {
     printf("recv failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
     } else
            {
             pChunkData = &recv_data;
            chunkLen = sizeof(pChunkData);
            XcpIp_RxCallback ((uint16) chunkLen, (char*) pChunkData, (uint16) port);
            }


        }

}
```

The above is a server socket program : I created a socket for accepting the connection with ip address and port number. my program is keep on accepting the connection and whenever it accepts a connection then it should come out of the for loop. Hoe to make the above program to comeout of the loop when it accepts a connection ??
Could anyone please help me.

I modified the above code and added main program. After accepting the connection from the client. Then I am getting output as recv failed with error. Control is going to the while loop and displaying as :recv failed with error inside the main function. Why is it like that ??

Comment: If you want to handle only 1 connection, just put `break` in `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `break` statement. It can be used to exit any kind of loop.

Or, of course, make the `accept()` the condition of the loop:

```
while( (fd = accept(...)) >= 0)
{
}
```

that makes it clear immediately when reading the code that "ah, here's a loop that runs for as long as we're able to accept incoming connections".

When you "bury" the exit condition inside and use `break`, it becomes harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `---->`

```
while(1)

{

 //conditon for break
if(fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Accept failed\n");
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I modified the above code and added main program. After accepting the connection from the client. Then I am getting output as recv failed with error. Control is going to the while loop and displaying as :recv failed with error inside the main function. Why is it like that ??

Comment: I edited the above code and added receive function. Client will be sending the connection for the first three times to server for accepting the connection. I don't have to worry about client. Client is an INCA tool which will be sending the connection request to the server. the above code is just accepting a connection only once. I am accepting the connection within the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

well done dude. Just put `break` in else part.

```
for(;;)   // accepting the connection continuously
    {
        len  = sizeof(client);
    fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

    if(fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Accept failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("\n Process incoming connection from (%s , %d)", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),ntohs(client.sin_port));
    break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you continue on failure and break on success?